# Equinumerosity of strings and natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

so I'm trying to show that there exists a bijection from the infinite set of finite strings composed of elements from $\{a, b\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. So I was thinking about showing that $\mathbb{N}$ and the infinite set of finite binary sequences are equinumerous (each have a unique representation), and then constructing a bijection between $\{a, b\}$  and $\{0, 1\}$. Then by the transitive property of equinumerosity, I would be done with my goal.

However, when you're writing something in binary, like 00001 (which would be equivalent to aaaab), and so I think this proof would exclude some cases? How else can I go about this?

Comment: It's generally *much* easier to find an injection in each direction and use Cantor–Bernstein to conclude existence of a bijection for this sort of problem.

Comment: I think you're fine; omit the leading $1$ of the binary string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order the strings first by length and then alphabetically. So that the empty string corresponds to $0$, "a" corresponds to $1$, $b$ to 2, $aa$ to 3, and so on.

Comment: so it would be null-0, a-1, b-2, aa-3, ab-4, ba-5, bb-6, aaa-7, aab-8, aba-9, abb-10, baa-11, bab-12, bba-13, bbb-14, aaaa-15, so on?

Comment: Yes, it is called the [shortlex order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [shortlex order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order) as in saulspatz's answer, but you could also adapt your trick with binary numbers.

Do you agree that the map $u \to bu$ defines a bijection from $\{a,b\}^*$ to $b\{a,b\}^*$? Now use your bijection $a \to 0$, $b \to 1$ to get a bijection from $b\{a,b\}^*$ to $1\{0,1\}^*$. Then $1\{0,1\}^*$ is the set of all positive integers written in binary. If you want to include zero, just consider the bijection $\Bbb N-\{0\} \to \Bbb N$ defined by $n \to n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

If your alphabet is $\{0, 1\}$, a simple way to describe the bijection with $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, \dotsc\}$ is to stick an 1 in front of the string, and read the result as a binary number. To go the other way around, write the number in binary and chop off the first digit.

The general case for an arbitrary alphabet is called [bijective numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration)

Comment: This leaves out the number $1$, I think instead of fixing it so that $0$ to $\epsilon$ you should subtract $1$ from the result of the procedure that adds a $1$ to the front of the binary string.

Comment: @jMdA, thanks for pointing out the thinko.